NFT mint transaction insturaction
is there any way to just get TransactionInsturaction for Mint?
async function mintNft() {
    const candyMachine = await METAPLEX
        .candyMachines()
        .findByAddress({ address: new PublicKey(CANDY_MACHINE_ID) }); 
    let { nft, response } = await METAPLEX.candyMachines().mint({
        candyMachine,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: WALLET.publicKey,
        },{commitment:'finalized'})

This codes "response" return "SendAndConfirmTransactionResponse" but i need transaction insturaction for using my solana blink
